# Fetch failed with protocol status: exception(16), lastModified=0: Http code=406, url=https://www.randolphnj.org/

Tags: nutch, http-status-code-406

I am trying to crawl url: https://www.randolphnj.org/

But it is showing this error

```
2020-09-22 15:03:08,395 INFO httpclient.Http: http.accept = text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
2020-09-22 15:03:08,395 INFO httpclient.Http: http.enable.cookie.header = true
2020-09-22 15:03:08,399 INFO conf.Configuration: found resource httpclient-auth.xml at file:/tmp/hadoop-unjar7802696204891280694/httpclient-auth.xml

Fetch failed with protocol status: exception(16), lastModified=0: Http code=406, url=https://www.randolphnj.org/
```

may I know what is the reason.kindly help me to solve.

Comment: The error shouldn't appear imo because the accepted mime `text/html` is sent by the server. On the other hand, the server software is massively outdated..

Comment: may I know the reason why it is not accepting the mime-type text/html.

Comment: Of course, if someone finds out. You could try accepting `*/*` tho and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the server is blocking requests when the HTTP request header "User-agent" includes the string "Nutch". I was able to reproduce the behavior using wget:

```
$> wget --header='User-Agent: mycrawler/Nutch-1.17' https://www.randolphnj.org/
--2020-09-25 10:55:42--  https://www.randolphnj.org/
Resolving www.randolphnj.org (www.randolphnj.org)... 63.247.128.112
Connecting to www.randolphnj.org (www.randolphnj.org)|63.247.128.112|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 406 Not Acceptable
2020-09-25 10:55:43 ERROR 406: Not Acceptable.

$> wget https://www.randolphnj.org/
--2020-09-25 11:02:25--  https://www.randolphnj.org/
Resolving www.randolphnj.org (www.randolphnj.org)... 63.247.128.112
Connecting to www.randolphnj.org (www.randolphnj.org)|63.247.128.112|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’
```

Comment: yes I tried to reproduce error nutch is concating the agentname as Nutch-1.17.

Comment: How to keep the keep same name.